# Strange error on tkinter concerning tk.Label.configure()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've got a problem when I was trying to do some stuff with tkinter 8.6 on python 3.11.
When I was trying to update a label with the method configure, it did nothing, and whene I closed the window, this error occurred :

```
File "C:\Users\\%user%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1692, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!label2"
```

My code is structured like this :

```
    Root (tk.Tk())
    |window (tk.Toplevel(root))
    ||second_window (tk.Toplevel(window))
```

I want to update a label with the parent 'window', by a function executed by a button in the 'second_window'.
I've tried with the configure method :

```
    label = tk.Label(window,text=<a string>)
    label.configure(text=<some random string>)
```

I think that the error come from the heredity system.
Thanks for help ;)

Comment: When I search for the "Invalid command name" error, they all point to trying to use a widget after it has been destroyed. Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This error is telling you the label has been destroyed.